# How to hide a field from the HTML form in the browsable Django Rest API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The question pretty much explains everything. If the URL allows POST, then a form is generated at the bottom, provided proper permissions are met. How do I exclude a field from that form?

Note: I am using Django Rest Framework, and the form I am talking about is the form generated by the framework in the browsable API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any info from your `form`, but `DjangoForm` has `exclude` property for that, you can access it via`self.exclude`, also its type is a `list`, so you can append wanted field into that to exclude it

```
class Meta:
    model = Model
    exclude = ['field1', 'field2', ...]
```

Comment: Please see the note I added to the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your fields are generated by a serializer, you can override it on some condition

Answer (score 0):

```
item = Items.objects.get(pk=1).defer('field1')
serializer = MySerializer(item)
```

Comment: can explain what this does ?

Comment: exclude the field on the original queryset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer

Answer (score 0):

You can give only required fields in serializer class like this

```
class Meta:
        model = Model_name
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'field1',
            'field2'
        )
```